# how to change var def to accept user input

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to get the `var def` to be user input in typescript. How could I get that done. The below are the codes please help.

```
var def = '';

let abc = document.getElementById("searchbar").innerHTML = def;
```

Comment: I am not able to understand the question

Comment: have got any error? what behavior you have  observed by this code?

Comment: Please specify your problem. It is not clear

Comment: I am trying the use the variable def as a userinput and put it as the values of innerHTML of the searchbar

Comment: Please Explain your problem

Comment: you can directly do this using 

    var def = document.getElementById("TextBoxId").value;

Comment: now the var def is empty but I want to var def to contain some input that is entered by the user how do I get that done in typescript they do not have the .value property

Comment: You can take a textbox and get that value and assign in into **def**

Comment: Still not getting you

Comment: can you please explain using a simple image

Comment: as i understand, you need to use `[(ngModel)]` for it

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get the var def to be user input in typescript.

Use and `input` element and its `onchange` event.

## Docs

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change